# Firestore - Cost when I get the parent document Id of the sub-collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Would I be charged for a read when I get the parent document ID of the sub-collection ?

```
export const GetAllMySubCollectionWithFieldHello = async () => {
  const query = await firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("MySubCollection").where("MyField", "==", "Hello").get();
  query.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data()); // Cost me one read for each document found
    console.log(doc.ref.parent.parent.id); // This line will it cost me one read again ?
  });
};
```

Comment: No, this data is downloaded anyway, as part of the object path. Getting id won't cost you anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that your `.get` will incur one read per document.  I don't believe that the `doc.data()` method incurs any cost.

`doc.ref.parent.parent.id` shouldn't incur any cost.  You are not reading anything from Firestore.  You can run this command even when offline.

Comment: That's indeed correct Jason. Since the parent ID can be determine from the path, there's no charge for getting that ID. If OP were to read the parent document itself though, that *would* be another charged document read (if the document has to be read on the server)..

Comment: @Jason Berryman "You are not reading anything from Firestore" => Not true. I read the documentation a lot and watch the videos from the Firebase channel. It was just not very clear to me and impossible to find this info when I usually find all the info.

Anyway, thank you all for your responses.

Comment: `doc.ref.parent.parent.id` will only return an ID.  It will not incur any cost.  However, if you use `doc.ref.parent.parent.get()` it *will* incur the cost of a document read, as it will read the document from Cloud Firestore.